# How to use G'MIC/ImageMagick to restore the text quality in an image?

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick, image-manipulation, gmic

I would like to **convert images** of blurred text, like this:

[image]

Into a quality similar to this, with sharp edges and not "pixilated":

[image]

**Background:** I'm currently working on pipelines to upgrade the video qualities of recorded classes. I intend to do that frame by frame. So far, I need a command to transform this category of images (mainly with text) into better-quality ones.

**My problem is**, I don't know and I didn't find any specific filters that could be helpful.

Comment: Have a look at the Lucy-Richardson method. (For the PSF, consider using a blurred dot.)

Comment: Can you post (part of) the image at full size? It is also possible that this is already doable in a video editor (likely a blend of contrast and sharpening).